# How can I empty trash in ubuntu 14.04? (It stopped working after upgrade from 13.10)

Tags: 14.04

I right click on app and it switches to "empty trash" but then prepares and times out...I go into trash and click on the empty icon but the same thing happens...I try to shift delete all or just one item and it still does not work!

Comment: which file are you deleting does the file have permission to move it or delete it

Comment: there is a music video downloaded from youtube, empty file folders from my desktop, and other folders that were not created by me also with nothing inside...

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/users/272357/agha-rehan-abbas